Filling a specific area with tikz
I am trying to fill a specific area in my tikz picture but didn't manage to do it correctly. It is a wave shape so it makes it a bit tricky to fill since it's not perfectly sinusoidal (on purpose).
Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you in advance,
Best regards.
CODE :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
% Define colors
\definecolor{filmColor}{rgb}{0.5, 0.7, 0.9}
\definecolor{plateColor}{rgb}{0.3, 0.3, 0.3}
\definecolor{elasticFilmColor}{rgb}{1.0, 0.4, 0.7}
% Plate
\fill[plateColor] (0,0) rectangle (10,0.5);
% Film
\fill[filmColor] (0,0.5) -- (0,1.5) .. controls (1,1.7) and (2,1.3) .. (3,1.5) .. controls (4,1.7) and (5,1.3) .. (6,1.5) .. controls (7,1.7) and (8,1.3) .. (9,1.5) -- (10,1.5) -- (10,0.5) -- cycle;
    % Elastic film (pink) on top of the liquid film
    \fill[elasticFilmColor] 
    (0,1.5) .. controls (1,1.7) and (2,1.3) .. (3,1.5) 
    .. controls (4,1.7) and (5,1.3) .. (6,1.5) 
    .. controls (7,1.7) and (8,1.3) .. (9,1.5) 
    -- (10,1.5)
    .. controls (9,1.9) and (8,1.5) .. (7,1.7)
    .. controls (6,1.9) and (5,1.5) .. (4,1.7)
    .. controls (3,1.9) and (2,1.5) .. (1,1.7)
    -- cycle;

    % Top of the elastic film
    \draw[elasticFilmColor] (0,1.7) 
    .. controls (1,1.9) and (2,1.5) .. (3,1.7) 
    .. controls (4,1.9) and (5,1.5) .. (6,1.7) 
    .. controls (7,1.9) and (8,1.5) .. (9,1.7) 
    -- (10,1.7);
     \fill[elasticFilmColor] 
    (0,1.7) .. controls (1,1.9) and (2,1.5) .. (3,1.7) 
    .. controls (4,1.9) and (5,1.5) .. (6,1.7) 
    .. controls (7,1.9) and (8,1.5) .. (9,1.7) 
    -- (10,1.7) -- cycle;
    
\draw[stealth-stealth,red,thin] (9.5, 0.5) -- (9.5, 1.5) node[pos=0.5,left] {$h_0$};
\draw[stealth-stealth,red,thin] (6.7, 0.5) -- (6.7, 1.55) node[pos=0.5,left] {$h(x,t)$};
\draw[dashed,black,very thin] (0, 1.5) -- (9.5, 1.5);
% Axes and labels
\draw[-stealth,red,thick] (0, 0.5) -- (0, 2) node[left] {$e_y$};
\draw[-stealth,red,thick] (0, 0.5) -- (11, 0.5) node[below] {$e_x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Croquis représentant la configuration standard de l'instabilité de Rayleigh-Taylor. Un fluide plus dense (ex : huile silicone) surplombe un fluide de densité moindre (ex : air) et est légèrement déformé à son interface.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

RENDERING :


Looks like you can draw a filled blue rectangle first and OVER it the wavy red region next. Will appear like having been filled …

As suggested by MS-SPO, draw first a large pink region (the elastic film) and hide the undesired part with the blue one (the film).
Example :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
  % Define colors
  \definecolor{filmColor}{rgb}{0.5, 0.7, 0.9}
  \definecolor{plateColor}{rgb}{0.3, 0.3, 0.3}
  \definecolor{elasticFilmColor}{rgb}{1.0, 0.4, 0.7}

  % Plate
  \fill[plateColor] (0,0) rectangle (10,0.5);

  % Elastic film
  \fill[elasticFilmColor] (10,0.5) -- (0,.5)  -- (0,1.7)
  .. controls (1,1.9) and (2,1.5) .. (3,1.7)
  .. controls (4,1.9) and (5,1.5) .. (6,1.7)
  .. controls (7,1.9) and (8,1.5) .. (9,1.7)
  -- (10,1.7) -- cycle;

  % Film
  \fill[filmColor] (0,0.5) -- (0,1.5)
  .. controls (1,1.7) and (2,1.3) .. (3,1.5)
  .. controls (4,1.7) and (5,1.3) .. (6,1.5)
  .. controls (7,1.7) and (8,1.3) .. (9,1.5)
  -- (10,1.5) -- (10,0.5) -- cycle;

  \draw[stealth-stealth,red,thin] (9.5, 0.5) -- (9.5, 1.5) node[pos=0.5,left] {$h_0$};
  \draw[stealth-stealth,red,thin] (6.7, 0.5) -- (6.7, 1.55) node[pos=0.5,left] {$h(x,t)$};
  \draw[dashed,black,very thin] (0, 1.5) -- (9.5, 1.5);
  % Axes and labels
  \draw[-stealth,red,thick] (0, 0.5) -- (0, 2) node[left] {$e_y$};
  \draw[-stealth,red,thick] (0, 0.5) -- (11, 0.5) node[below] {$e_x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


